# Determine if $(this) element within jQuery each loop hasClass like a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Within a jQuery each loop, how can I determine if a selected $(this) element contains a class with a name 'like' a specific value.  Initially hasClass() looked promising, but it's unclear to me how to use that function to handle this.

Here is the markup.

```
<div class="command_buttons">
    <a class="download_left_button" style="display:none;" href="#"></a>
    <a class="bookmark_left_button" href="#"></a>
    <a class="search_right_button" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript.

```
findButtonPositionOnCommandBar = function (buttonType) {
  /* This function returns 'solo', 'left', 'center', or 'right' text
     to tell the button position. The buttonType param should match
     a button class prefix like 'bookmark', 'search', or 'download'. */

  if ($('.command_buttons').length == 0) { return ''; } // Command bar not found.

  // How many visible buttons are on the first command bar found on the page?
  var $visibleButtons = $('.command_buttons:first a:visible');
  var numberOfButtons = $($visibleButtons).length;
  if (numberOfButtons == 0) { return ''; }
  if (numberOfButtons == 1) { return 'solo'; }

  // This is where I'm having difficulty.
  // Find the button with a class name LIKE buttonType_.
  buttonSelector = 'class*=' + buttonType + '_'; 
  $($visibleButtons).each(function (index) {
     if ($(this).hasClass(buttonSelector)) {
        alert('true: ' + index);
     } else {
        alert('false: ' + index);
     }
  });
},
```

For instance, with the above function if we passed 'bookmark' to the buttonType parameter, then it needs to locate anchor tag which has a class of 'bookmark_left_button'.

We have a variety of buttons that can appear in various positions.  So I would prefer to find 'bookmark_' rather than write a select for all the permutations of classes that we can apply to the buttons (i.e. bookmark_left_button, bookmark_center_button, bookmark_right_button, download_left_button, etc).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Always jsfiddle code that is as specific as this.

Comment: CAn you change the HTML to add "bookmark" as an additional class? eg `class="bookmark bookmark_left_button"`. Or if you have bookmark separate you could potentially make your left and right button code more generic... This would seem a nicer option at a glance...

Comment: I agree with @Chris - that's a much simpler way of doing this, if it's possible.

Comment: @Chris, I agree, adding a separate 'bookmark' class would make this easier to handle. Right now we're just trying to hot-fix something that another developer will be re-factoring next sprint.  I'll suggest this to her.  Our current problem is that command bar markup is in numerous places all over the web project, so simplifying by adding that class entails additional risk that I'm trying to avoid right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
buttonSelector = buttonType + '_'; 
$($visibleButtons).each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).attr("class").search(buttonSelector) != -1) {
        alert('true: ' + index);
    } else {
        alert('false: ' + index);
    }
});
```

It just does a string search in the `class` attribute to see if `buttonType_` is there.

Comment: There is no reason to use `attr()` when `hasClass` is perfectly sufficient and much cleaner.

Comment: @DesertIvy Does `hasClass` work with wildcards, because that's what the question is about.

Comment: @Archer, that was it!
http://jsfiddle.net/Stormjack/3kc9T/1/
Thanks to everyone who helped with this.

Answer (score 1):

<s>It's sufficient to do:</s>

```
if ($(this).hasClass(buttonType)) {
```

So:

```
.hasClass("bookmark")
```

You're trying to do a partial match. This indicates that your class names aren't set up properly.

If you have classes like:

```
.bookmark-item {}
.bookmark-header {}
.search-item {}
.search-header {}
```

And you want to match all `bookmark-*` elements you should reorganize your classes to:

```
.bookmark.item {}
.bookmark.header {}
.search.item {}
.search.header {}
/*     ^- note that there is no space here */
```

Your html will be: `<div class="bookmark item"></div>`

This allows you to match classes with `.hasClass("bookmark")`

---

In case you're unclear about the CSS syntax:

```
.bookmark .item {}
```

Matches:

```
<div class="bookmark"><div class="item"></div></div>
```

Whereas

```
.bookmark.item {}
```

Matches:

```
<div class="bookmark item"></div>
```

Comment: But isn't the point that it doesn't have a class called `bookmark` which is why that won't work. Or are you saying that `hasClass` automaticaly checks for substrings of classes as well which would seem wrong to me (without looking up the API).

Comment: Oh I see. I misunderstood OPs question. I assumed he had a class called `bookmark`. OP is trying to do a partial match, this indicates to me that his classes aren't set up properly. There is no reason to not split a class-name.

Comment: @Frits van Campen, I hear you.  That's more of a re-factor that we can address next sprint.  Right now I'm just trying to get something fixed for another developer today.  From what I'm seeing, hasClass() doesn't have a related hasClassLike() that can wildcard the class search in a way that the selector [class*=foo] can do.  Back to the original question, is there a way to do what I'm asking within an each loop?

Answer (score 0):

When looping over elements using `each()`, the function callback uses two variables: `index`, a number that increments with each pass, and `value`, the actual node itself; so you need to reference `value`.

```
$($visibleButtons).each(function (index, value) {
     if ($(value).hasClass(buttonType)) {
        alert('true: ' + index);
     } else {
        alert('false: ' + index);
     }
  });
```

Comment: `$(value)` `value` is a dom node. additionally `buttonSelector` contains more than a classname, which is the true issue.

Comment: Good point, didn't catch that. I've updated my post accordingly.

Comment: You've addressed half of the comment but buttonType is still not a full class name so does `hasClass` really actually work here?

Comment: @Kevin B, that buttonSelector in my original code was my initial attempt at this.  I think Archer has the right idea, just changing it to buttonSelector = buttonType + '_';  And to be clear, those alerts were just for triage, the function will actually do something else once it's able to determine if the $(this) button has a class of 'buttonType_*' there.  It just seems odd that there is a way to wildcard the selector via $(element[class*=foo]) or  $(element[class^=foo]) but no similar suite of jQuery functions that can be called like the .hasClass() function.